# mimicking a next method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller method that (together with code not shown below) renders a message according to the current number of the message index, which gets incremented each call. There are six messages in the database, and everything's working fine for the first three messages, but once the index is getting to 3 (it's set to zero in the initialization method), the `next_message` method is returning the message at index 0, and it keeps circling through the first three messages rather than moving onto the fourth message. My only goal for this code is to retrieve all 6 messages in the database and display them one by one.

Can you explain why this might be happening? Puts statements are showing that the index is definitely getting incremented. Note, I'm a crappy amateur programmer anyways, so I realize the code is probably ugly and inefficient (for example, querying for every message on each call seems wasteful) so if there's a way to improve it while fixing the problem, I would be eternally grateful.

```
def next_,essage
   #... (some code ommitted)
   session[:message_index] += 1
   messages = Message.all
   message_index = session[:message_index]
   next_msg = messages[message_index]

   render :json {:next_message => next_msg}
end
```

Comment: We'll likely need more information.

Comment: So you don't see a problem with the code I posted?

Comment: The code barely does anything, and it's obvious what it does--if it's doing something other than you expect, debug it. Otherwise the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I thought maybe that code Message.all isn't always returning them in the same order, therefore, if it could be rewritten another way, it might also fix the problem I'm having.

Comment: It will return them in natural order; if you want to force a specific order, add an `order`.

Comment: @Michael, The last edit really was radical and appears to have not been done by you. Source code changes by others are not considered kosher in the question, so if you didn't do it, you are free to "rollback" the change by clicking the "edited" link above the name of the person editing it, or tell one of us with higher points and we'll revert it for you. While your code isn't idiomatic Ruby, that's something we can deal with separately.

Comment: I'm the op and I voted to close this question. The problem seems to have occurred because the initial rake db:seed was aborted midway through, and when I seeded it a second time, it started from the point where it was aborted. In short, the messages were getting rendered in the right order according to how they were repeated in the db.